# Rails 4 + Devise: Send welcome email with password reset instructions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, change-password

I have my registrations set up such that I create the account for a user with a predetermined password, then I would like to send them a welcome email, with a link to the Devise `edit_user_password_url`.

My method fails because when the User follows the link, they see the following: "You can't access this page without coming from a password reset email. If you do come from a password reset email, please make sure you used the full URL provided."

**How can I make my welcome email include the proper link for password reset?**

```
# RegistrationsController
def create
     if params[:user] && !params[:user][:password]
         params[:user][:password] = "testpassword" #obviously not real
         build_resource(sign_up_params)
         puts sign_up_params

            resource.save
            yield resource if block_given?
            if resource.persisted?
                if resource.active_for_authentication?
                    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
                    NewUserMailer.new_user_email(resource).deliver_now
                    redirect_to users_path
                else
                    set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
                    expire_data_after_sign_in!
                    respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
                end
            else
                render :new, :address => params[:address]
            end
     else
         super
     end
end

#email 
Welcome, follow this link to update your password <%= link_to "My account", edit_user_password_url %></p>
```

Comment: Either send 2 emails one is welcome and other is reset password email at once upon registration or just send only reset password email upon registration as reset password form needs reset_token to edit password otherwise it will give error

Comment: For send reset password email like : `user.send_reset_password_instructions`